# How to assign a multiple line value to a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable `FOO` with me that needs to be assigned with a value that will be multiple lines. Something like this,

```
FOO="This is line 1
     This is line 2
     This is line 3"
```

So when I print the value of `FOO` it should give the following output.

```
echo $FOO
output:
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Furthermore, the number of lines will be decided dynamically as I will initialize it using a loop.

The answers that have been shown in the other question using mainly `read -d` is not suitable for me as I am doing intensive string operations and the code format is also important.

Comment: Remove leading whitespaces in line 2 and 3 and use: `echo "$FOO"`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't indent the lines or you'll get extra spaces. Use quotes when you expand `"$FOO"` to ensure the newlines are preserved.

```
$ FOO="This is line 1 
This is line 2   
This is line 3"
$ echo "$FOO"
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Another way is to use `\n` escape sequences. They're interpreted inside of `$'...'` strings.

```
$ FOO=$'This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3'
$ echo "$FOO"
```

A third way is to store the characters `\` and `n`, and then have `echo -e` interpret the escape sequences. It's a subtle difference. The important part is that `\n` isn't interpreted inside of regular quotes.

```
$ FOO='This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3'
$ echo -e "$FOO"
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

You can see the distinction I'm making if you remove the `-e` option and have `echo` print the raw string without interpreting anything.

```
$ echo "$FOO"
This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3
```

Comment: Hi John, your example code works for me! However, in the first example above, when I echo the variable with ```echo $FOO``` without putting $FOO between the quotation marks, the output is on the same line. Do you know why? I'm using GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That's what happens when you don't have quotes. The value is subject to *word splitting* and *glob expansion*. Instead of `echo` being told to print one argument with embedded newlines, each word of `$FOO` becomes a separate argument with no newlines. It's as if you wrote `echo This is line 1 This is line 2 This is line 3`. Bottom line: always quote variable expansions unless you actually want it to be subject to word splitting and globbing (rare).

Answer (score 4):

When you initialize `FOO` you should use line breaks: `\n`.

```
FOO="This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3"
```

Then use `echo -e` to output `FOO`.

> It is important to note that `\n` inside `"..."` is NOT a line break, but literal `\` , followed by literal `n`. It is *only when interpreted by `echo -e`* that this literal sequence is converted to a newline character. — wise words from [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

---

```
#!/bin/bash

FOO="This is line 1\nThis is line 2\nThis is line 3"
echo -e $FOO

Output:
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Comment: Its giving output as `-e This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3`

Comment: @juned You need a version of `echo` which supports `-e`. Bash's built-in echo command does, as does GNU's `/bin/echo` binary.

Comment: No that worked when I ran script with `./script.sh` but with `sh scripname` it ddin't

Comment: Don't run scripts with `sh script.sh`. It overrides the interpreter the script wants, instead using plain `sh`. Type `./script.sh` to ensure the correct interpreter is used.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I added your comment to my answer @mklement0 , feel free to edit it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the lines to a variable using read lines:

```
$ read -r -d '' FOO << EOF
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
EOF
```

To see the newline on printing use quotes around the variable: (`echo "$FOO"` not `echo $FOO`)

```
$ echo "$FOO"
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```